# Mysql foreign keys and allow null on existing field

Tags: mysql, null, foreign-keys, innodb

So I am changing the scope on a database, and need to make a field which is a foreign key, allow null values.

I am doing this in phpmyadmin, but the query is below

```
ALTER TABLE `nuggets` CHANGE `n_st_id` `n_st_id` INT( 11 ) NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

It tells me the query ran successfully, but its showing null as no, and default as 0. Its an innodb table, any ideas why its not letting me change it?

Answer (score 1):

It was because it was indexed, I had to remove the indexes and then set it, then reset the indexes